# Does the GHC garbage collector have any special optimisations for large objects?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Does the GHC garbage collector handle "large" objects specially? Or does it treat them exactly the same as any other object?

Some GC engines put large objects in a separate area, which gets scanned less regularly and possibly has a different collection algorithm (e.g., compacting instead of copying, or maybe even using freelists rather than attempting to defragment). Does GHC do anything like this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. The GHC heap is not kept in one contiguous stretch of memory; rather, it is [organized into blocks](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/BlockAlloc).

When an allocated object’s size is above a specific threshold (block_size*8/10, where block_size is 4k, so roughly 3.2k), the block holding the object is marked as large (BF_LARGE).  Now, when garbage collection occurs, rather than copy large objects from this block to a new one, the block itself is added to the new generation's set of blocks; this involves fiddling with a linked list (a large object list, to be precise).

Since this means that it may take a while for us to reclaim dead space inside a large block, it does mean that large objects can suffer from fragmentation, as seen in bug [7831](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7831). However, this doesn't usually occur until individual allocations hit half of the megablock size, 1M.

Comment: Shouldn't the block_size be 5k, and threshold 4k in the example?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right that I flipped the multiplication. block_size is 4k; threshold is ~3.2k; I've fixed it up.